Bin a polars column in the same way as pandas.cut
I'm trying to use polars.Series.cut to reproduce the data binning behavior of pandas.cut.
MRE of values and breakpoints:
scores = [1111, 65, 88, -1111, 92]
breaks = [0, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]

With pandas.cut, the bin is null if the value is outside the defined edges:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'score': scores})
df['bin'] = pd.cut(df['score'], breaks)

#    score            bin
# 0   1111            NaN  <- null in pandas
# 1     65   (60.0, 70.0]
# 2     88   (80.0, 90.0]
# 3  -1111            NaN  <- null in pandas
# 4     92  (90.0, 100.0]

But with polars.Series.cut, it seems we're forced to include the (-inf, ...] and (..., inf] bins:
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({'score': scores})
df = df.with_columns(bin=pl.col('score').cut(breaks))

# shape: (5, 2)
# ┌───────┬────────────┐
# │ score ┆ bin        │
# │ ---   ┆ ---        │
# │ i64   ┆ cat        │
# ╞═══════╪════════════╡
# │ 1111  ┆ (100, inf] │  <- not null in polars
# │ 65    ┆ (60, 70]   │
# │ 88    ┆ (80, 90]   │
# │ -1111 ┆ (-inf, 0]  │  <- not null in polars
# │ 92    ┆ (90, 100]  │
# └───────┴────────────┘

How can we replicate the pandas.cut bins in Polars?

What about using is_between as a filter?
df.with_columns(bin=pl.when(pl.col('score').is_between(breaks[0], breaks[-1], closed='right'))
                      .then(pl.col('score').cut(breaks))
               )

Or, better, to avoid recomputing the category, pre-filter:
df.with_columns(bin=pl.when(pl.col('score').is_between(breaks[0], breaks[-1], closed='right'))
                      .then(pl.col('score')).cut(breaks)
               )

Output:
┌───────┬───────────┐
│ score ┆ bin       │
│ ---   ┆ ---       │
│ i64   ┆ cat       │
╞═══════╪═══════════╡
│ 1111  ┆ null      │
│ 65    ┆ (60, 70]  │
│ 88    ┆ (80, 90]  │
│ -1111 ┆ null      │
│ 92    ┆ (90, 100] │
└───────┴───────────┘


Just noticed that we should use in_between(..., closed='right') to match the cut() intervals (I was sloppy with the MRE and didn't include the outermost values)

Just for completeness, if you already have the DataFrame with categorical data, you can also compare to str to set the values to None:
df.with_columns(
    pl.when(
        ~pl.col('bin').cast(pl.Utf8).str.contains('inf')
    ).then(pl.col('bin'))
)

┌───────┬───────────┐
│ score ┆ bin       │
│ ---   ┆ ---       │
│ i64   ┆ cat       │
╞═══════╪═══════════╡
│ 1111  ┆ null      │
│ 65    ┆ (60, 70]  │
│ 88    ┆ (80, 90]  │
│ -1111 ┆ null      │
│ 92    ┆ (90, 100] │
└───────┴───────────┘

Or you can exclude first() and last() categories:
df.with_columns(
    pl.when(
        pl.col('bin') != pl.col('bin').cat.get_categories().first(),
        pl.col('bin') != pl.col('bin').cat.get_categories().last(),
    ).then(pl.col('bin'))
)

┌───────┬───────────┐
│ score ┆ bin       │
│ ---   ┆ ---       │
│ i64   ┆ cat       │
╞═══════╪═══════════╡
│ 1111  ┆ null      │
│ 65    ┆ (60, 70]  │
│ 88    ┆ (80, 90]  │
│ -1111 ┆ null      │
│ 92    ┆ (90, 100] │
└───────┴───────────┘


Good to know, thanks. Also, I'm a little surprised that bin= isn't needed here. I guess polars just infers bin= from the then()?
